# How to search for list of keywords from text file using buffered stream I/O Java

Tags: java, string, file, search, bufferedstream

I am new to programming and still studying in uni. I got an assignment and I am confused. I need to search for a list of keywords using Buffered Stream I/O and return the line that contains the keywords. Please help me as I don't know how to do it.
My code is as below and it shows the

```
public class BufferedIO {
private String outFile = "Result.txt";
private String responseFile = "ResposeTime.txt";
private long startTime, elapsedTime;  // for speed benchmarking
private int bufferSizeKB = 1;
private int bufferSize = bufferSizeKB * 2048;
private String resultHolder;
Map<String, String> keywordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
BufferedInputStream bIn = null;
FileInputStream fIn = null;

public void ReadBufferedIOStream(String searchKeyword, String inFile) {
    // Using Buffered Stream I/O
    System.out.println("Reading file using Buffered Stream");
    try (BufferedInputStream bIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile))) {
        try( BufferedOutputStream resp =
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(responseFile))) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int bytesCount;
        byte[] contents = new byte[80]; 
        while ((bytesCount = bIn.read(contents)) != -1) {
            resultHolder = new String(contents, 0, bytesCount);
            if(resultHolder.contains(searchKeyword)) {
                //System.out.println("\n "+resultHolder);
                keywordMap.put(searchKeyword, resultHolder);
                System.out.println("this is map "+keywordMap);
            }
            out.write(contents, 0, bytesCount); 
        }
        elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        //System.out.println("The output file contains \n"+out);
        System.out.println("Elapsed Time is " + (elapsedTime / 1000000.0) + " msec");           
}   
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    finally {
        // close the streams using close method
        try {
            if (fIn != null) {
                fIn.close();
            }
            if (bIn != null) {
                bIn.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing stream : " + ioe);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it has to be a stream *only* and you *must not* use a reader? Because `BufferedReader` has `readLine()` reading an entire line from a text file.

Comment: yes because the assignment states to use buffered stream I/O.